# R Studio: Time Syncing Data Sets

Tags: r

I have a simple problem, and a bit more complicated twist at the end.

I have 2 datasets A & B (Separate when imported into R):

Dataset A is pulled from a DAQ that is sampling at 2000 times a second, while dataset B is pulled from a scope at 500 times a second. I have a test that records data from the DAQ and Scope for 5 seconds.

In R Studio I want to time synchronize this data and, for the sake of learning, how can I do it in both of the following ways?

1) Without duplicating values so filtering doesn't stair step:

```
       A         B
1      1         1 
2      2         NA
3      3         NA
4      4         NA
5      5         2
6      6         NA
7      7         NA
8      8         NA
9      9         3
10     10        NA
11     11        NA
12     12        NA
```

2) With duplicating numbers if I don't want NA's in the functions I apply to the frame:

```
       A         B
1      1         1 
2      2         1
3      3         1
4      4         1
5      5         2
6      6         2
7      7         2
8      8         2
9      9         3
10     10        3
11     11        3
12     12        3
```

Now here is the twist where it becomes a very unique problem I have. Lets say Dataset A records a bit before & after the 5 second test. Dataset A also has an extra column for "Trigger" which is either a 0 or a 1. 1 is a high that represents recording and basically where Dataset B starts. When it switches back to 0, Dataset B has finished recording.

Is there a way I can strategically do the above time sync in Dataset A? The reason I want to keep the data before & after the "true" recording section, is to make sure a filter or a filtfilt sweep will level out before the data truly starts.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `merge(dfA, dfB, by.x="Atimecolumnname", by.y="Btimecolumnname", all=TRUE)` and `zoo::na.locf` to convert `NA` to previous non-`NA` value.